# how to fetch an email body in mailcore2

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, imap, mailcore

I've trying to migrate from [mailcore](https://github.com/MailCore/MailCore/tree/master/Source) to [mailcore2](http://libmailcore.com/). Previously in mailcore, fetching a body structure was as simple as `[msg fetchBodyStructure]` where msg is a [CTCoreMessage](https://github.com/MailCore/MailCore/blob/master/Source/CTCoreMessage.h) object.

With mailcore2, things seem to be more complex. In [MCOIMAPSession's](http://libmailcore.com/mailcore2/api/Classes/MCOIMAPSession.html#//api/name/fetchMessageAttachmentByUIDOperationWithFolder:uid:partID:encoding:) documentation for fetching a message body, we have:

```
MCOIMAPFetchContentOperation * op = 
    [session fetchMessageAttachmentByUIDOperationWithFolder:@"INBOX"
                                                        uid:[message uid]
                                                     partID:"1.2"
                                                   encoding:[part encoding]];
 [op start:^(NSError * error, NSData * partData) {
 }];
```

I have absolutely no idea what this `1.2` is supposed to refer to. The authors refer the users to [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822), [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822), and [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) but none of them has a straightforward answer to the above.

Can someone please show me a simple code sample of fetching an entire message body?

Comment: How about changing the correct answer to Gal Blank's answer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure why people complicate things:
this is how you fetch email body with MailCore2:

```
MCOIMAPSession *session = [[MCOIMAPSession alloc] init];
    [session setHostname:@"imap.gmail.com"];
    [session setPort:993];
    [session setUsername:[UICKeyChainStore stringForKey:@"username"]];
    [session setPassword:[UICKeyChainStore stringForKey:@"password"]];
    [session setConnectionType:MCOConnectionTypeTLS];
    MCOIMAPFetchContentOperation *operation = [session fetchMessageByUIDOperationWithFolder:@"INBOX" uid:message.uid];

    [operation start:^(NSError *error, NSData *data) {
        MCOMessageParser *messageParser = [[MCOMessageParser alloc] initWithData:data];

        NSString *msgHTMLBody = [messageParser htmlBodyRendering];
        [webView loadHTMLString:msgHTMLBody baseURL:nil];
    }];
```

Comment: You would think this piece of code would be in the "getting started" guide. Thanks.

Comment: last line should be [webView.mainFrame loadHTMLString:msgHTMLBody baseURL:nil]

Answer (score 0):

You want RFC 3501, part 6.4.5 - Fetch Command, specifically `BODY[<section>]`.
The number refers to segments of the MIME structure of the message.

For example, if your messages mime structure looks like this, a common format:

```
multipart/alternative
|- text/plain
\- text/html
```

The parts and subparts are numbered recursively like this:

```
multipart/alternative (top-level)
|- text/plain (Part 1)
\- text/html (Part 2)
```

For a more complicated format, eg, with an attachment:

```
multipart/mixed (top-level)
|- multipart/alternative (Part 1)
|  |- text/plain (Part 1.1)
|  \- text/html (Part 1.2)
\- image/jpeg (Part 2)
```

If you want the entirety of the message, the part number is normally left blank.  Or you can use `TEXT` if you want the entirety of the message, but without the headers.

Comment: Excellent! Is there a way to fetch an email summary or something like the first three lines of the body to display it in the mailbox with out having to fetch the entire email?

Comment: I can't speak to mailcore, but from a protocol level, once you've gotten the `BODYSTRUCTURE`, so you can identify which part you consider to be the body, you could grab the first kb or so using a partial fetch if your library supports it.  `BODY[]<2048>` in the protocol.  I'm not sure how widely supported this is.

Comment: The question was about using the MailCore api. This answer doesn't look relevant to me.