# How do I fix "Use of undeclared identifier 'message'" using MailCore2?

Tags: objective-c, mailcore2

I keep getting this error with MailCore2.

> Use of undeclared identifier 'message'

How do I fix this?

Here's my code. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    MCOIMAPSession *session = [[MCOIMAPSession alloc] init];
    [session setHostname:@"imap.gmail.com"];
    [session setPort:993];
    [session setUsername:[UICKeyChainStore stringForKey:@"username"]];
    [session setPassword:[UICKeyChainStore stringForKey:@"password"]];
    [session setConnectionType:MCOConnectionTypeTLS];
    MCOIMAPFetchContentOperation *operation = [session fetchMessageByUIDOperationWithFolder:@"INBOX" uid:message.uid];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: There: `message.uid`  From where `message` comes from?

Comment: The error is pretty clear. There is no such variable as `message`.

Comment: I got this code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20074767/6763186). What type of variable would `message` be then?

Comment: Well, you should understand the code you pasted.

Comment: I understand most of it. Just not that particular part.

Comment: You seems to be missing some coding basic. Because `message` is defined nowhere in your code. You need to understand what is it, where is should be declared, what should be its value. Your issue is like `[webSiteURL absoluteString]`, but nowhere in the code there is a "NSURL *webSiteURL;`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the function call "fetchMessageByUIDOperationWithFolder" which means: get one message with a particular UID from a particular folder. That is why you have to specify the folder and the UID of the message that you want to get.

Your folder is set to "INBOX" - which is fine. 
Yet your variable "message", which is supposed to have a value for "uid" is not defined. 
Do you know the UID of the message you are trying to get here?
Then you can simply specify the variable with the value for your UID in the function call after the code part "uid:"

Note: it seems unlikely that in a 'didLoad' call you want to get only a single message, unless this is a didLoad call for a ViewController that just renders one message. You will still need to supply the value for the UID of the message you want to get to your code.