# How to omit the encode characters of imap email attachments inserted into mysql database

Tags: php, imap, decode, mime-types, email-attachments

After parsing the imap email, i insert it into the my database. The emails that have no attachments are insert well with no problem, but emails with attachment is a problem. When i insert, my body column in my table is filled with some crazy encoded characters. How can in decode or stop the email attachments being inserted into the database with those crazy characters. Here are soem examples: %PDF-1.7 %���� 1 0 obj en. Refer my code below and help please. Thanks.

```
 <?php

    $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password);

    $emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
    $totalemails = imap_num_msg($inbox);
      if($totalemails){
        echo $totalemails;
      }else{
          echo 'There are no emails.';
          }
          echo "<br><hr><br>";

    if($emails) {

        rsort($emails);

        foreach($emails as $email_number) {
            $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
            $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number);

            if(isset($structure->parts) && is_array($structure->parts) && isset($structure->parts[1])) {
                $part = $structure->parts[1];
                $body = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

              if($part->encoding == 3) {
                    $message = imap_base64($body);
                } else if($part->encoding == 1) {
                    $message = imap_qprint(imap_8bit($body));
                  } else if($part->encoding == 0) {
                    $message = $body;
                     } else if($part->encoding == 2) {
                    $message = imap_binary($body);
                    } else if($part->encoding == 4) {
                    $message = imap_qprint($body);
                } else {
                    $message = $body;
                }

            $status =($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread');
            $from = utf8_decode(imap_utf8($overview[0]->from));
            $date = utf8_decode(imap_utf8($overview[0]->date));
            $subject = utf8_decode(imap_utf8($overview[0]->subject));
        }
        echo "status: " . $status . "<br>";
        echo "subject: " . $subject . "<br>";
        echo "from: " . $from . "<br>";
        echo "date: " . $date . "<br>";
        echo "body: " . $message . "<br><hr><br>";

        //my insert into database code is here.

          imap_delete($inbox, $email_number);
        }
      }  

    // close the connection

    imap_close($inbox);
    ?>
```

Comment: What is it you want to do with the attachments?  You can't just omit the 'crazy' characters, as it won't be that attachment anymore.  PDFs have binary data.  You could not fetch them, you could store them elsewhere, you could not decode them...

Comment: Presumably your problem is that you want the body, you are always fetching part '2' which is not always the body.  You have to look at the body structure array and choose the part that is the body you want.  It is not in a fixed location for every message.

Comment: @Max, thanks. You got my point. I want to save it on my C drive. But my code above is inserting the some crazy data into the body column of my database and that is happening when the code above is reading and parsing emails with attachment only. The emails without attachments are ok. The body part is inserted with no issues. Its only happenning with emails with attachments. So where in my code above is that problem? Please figure out for me. Its been 2 weeks now while i have been trying to fix this. Please help.

Comment: If part 2 is wrong then which part will I fetch, part 1 or 0?

Comment: Depends on the message.  It could be 1, 2, 2.1, 1.2, etc.  See my answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034916/how-to-fetch-an-email-body-in-mailcore2/18035176#18035176 and & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787767/fetch-imap-body-message-by-telnet/37794152#37794152 for discussion of MIME layouts.

Comment: Ok thanks. My code above is taking the attachment as body text and inserting it into the database and maybe because the attachment is encoded, the inserted data is in some 'crazy' form likw these [%PDF-1.7 %���� 1 0 obj en]. How can i fix this? Thanks.

Comment: That's not encoded.  That's what a PDF file actually looks like.  It is a binary file, if you look at it like text, it's going to look crazy.

Comment: Thanks. How can i stop those binary characters inserted in my database?

Comment: You are going to have to reformulate the question.  What exactly are you trying to do?  Is it download bodies into your database?  If so, _don't download attachments_, and read my answers about how to find the body.  What is your ideal solution here?

Comment: Ok here: 1). I want to download the body, 2) i want to download the attachment and save it in c drive, 3) i  want to create a  link  to the downloaded attachment for users to click and open the downloaded attachment. From my imap_fetchstructure('$con','$email',1.2) function; it extracts the attachments and body part very well for emails with attachments, but for those emails that don't have attachments, the body part is not extracted by the function. If i change the last parameter to 2, it works for emails without attachment and not working for emails with attachment. Where is the error ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190840/discussion-between-max-and-kkambi).

Comment: ok..am there..please check me.